# Errors when trying to use CIKernel CoreImage/QuartzCore class on iOS

Tags: ios, import, automatic-ref-counting

Hi I'm trying to use the `CIKernel` class

I don't understand why is it that I keep getting these errors:

> AdriansFilter.m:23:29: error: receiver 'CIKernel' for class message is a forward declaration [4]
>
> AdriansFilter.m:23:28:{23:28-23:62}: error: no known class method for selector 'kernelsWithString:' [4]

I've tried importing QuartzCore framework but it still doesn't work. I'm stuck because I really cannot determine what is the real issue here. Could somebody help me please?

my h file looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface AdriansFilter: CIFilter
{
    CIImage   *inputImage;
    CIColor   *inputColor;
    NSNumber  *inputDistance;
    NSNumber  *inputSlope;
}

@end
```

my m file looks like this

```
#import "AdriansFilter.h"

@implementation AdriansFilter

static CIKernel *hazeRemovalKernel = nil;

- (id)init
{
    if(hazeRemovalKernel == nil)
    {
        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass: [self class]];
        NSString *code = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: [bundle
                                                                 pathForResource:    @"MyHazeRemoval"
                                                             ofType: @"cikernel"]];
        NSArray *kernels = [CIKernel kernelsWithString: code];

        hazeRemovalKernel = [kernels objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return [super init];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't imported a header where the interface for CIKernel is defined. By searching the [Apple developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/), I don't find a CIKernel class reference for iOS. This suggests to me that the CIKernel class is not available on iOS.

In Xcode, click on CIKernel in your source file to put the text cursor there, then open the right column (also known as Utilities) of the Xcode window, then select the quick help inspector tab. If the selected class is available for iOS, you should see documentation for the class and a reference to which header file declares it. When I try this with the CIKernel class selected in an iOS project, I just get "No Quick Help".

Comment: thanks! it seems to be available on OSX. How else might I be able to use CIKernel? Can use OSX libraries on iOS? I have to use it to apply custom filters to images but I'm unable to do so.

Comment: I think you'll need to find another solution for iOS. Take a look at the Core Image Programming Guide for iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html - This is beyond my area of expertise, but I understood the core problem in this case.